# Changing while loop to for loop

Tags: python

I was wondering if this same code could be made with a `for loop` instead of a `while`

```
d = 0.6
b  = 0.0
h = 0.0
t = 0.0
count = 0

h = float(input("enter height: "))
b = float(input("enter a number of bounces: "))

t = h

while count < b:
    if count == b - 1:
        t += h * d
        #print(t)
    else:
        h = h * d
        t += h * 2
        #print(t)
    count += 1
    #print (t)
print(t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GLHF reminded me, the `b` should be an int in order for the code below to work.
I see no reason for a variable `b`, representing a number of bounces to be a float. Moreover, in your original code you have a comparison between `count` (an int) and `b` (float from user input).
In a case, where b is not a float with a `0` for the decimal part, the check would fail, so you might want to change the line to `b = int(input('Enter the number of bounces))`

```
for count in range(b-1): # generates a sequence from 0 to b-2
    h *= d
    t += h * 2
    #print(t)
t += h * d
print(t)
```

[range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

Comment: you can't use a float in range function. It must be an integer. And if you use `round()` the result will change, check OP's variables first. This answer is far from what OP's want.

Comment: @GLHF That's true, thanks for pointing out. I guess I just read that b stands for bounces, which would naturally be int.

Comment: Also the result of your answer is not correct either, you should use range(b) instead of (b-1) and `if` - `else` statements.

Comment: @GLHF Actually the result is correct. Testing it in shell with both my and original code, using values `d,b,h,t = 0.6, 20, 2.5, 2.5` gives `9.999634384155991` as the answer.

Comment: @hlfrmn but op's codes result is : 19.066879999999998 . How is your result is correct then?

Comment: @GLHF I double checked. Please help me find the mistake, I really can't find it. http://pastebin.com/QsQkr1ED

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't change your variables from `float` type to `integer` you can't do it, because you need `range()` function and `range()` only accepts integer type.

If you set your variables to an integer instead of float, you can use it in a for loop like;

```
d = 0.6
b  = 6 #bounce
h = 5 #height
t = 0.0
count = 0

t = h

for x in range(b):
    if count == b-1:
        t += h*d
    else:
         h *= d
         t += h*2

    count += 1
print (t)
```